# How to use "hide Class" in Android?

Tags: android, java-native-interface, hide

There are some class hidden in the offical api, such as "
com.android.mms.model.SlideModel", but we can find them from the source code.
Are there any method that help us use the "hide class".
I search some information that said we need use JNI, however, I still don't understand how to use it.
Are there any body can give me a example?

Comment: Want to hide  source files (.java) or class files (.class)? Read : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_(software)

Answer (score 0):

> There are some class hidden in the offical api, such as " com.android.mms.model.SlideModel", but we can find them from the source code.

`com.android.mms.model.SlideModel` is from an application, not the operating system. It is not "hidden in the official api", any more than the Java classes implementing Angry Birds are "hidden in the official api".

> Are there any method that help us use the "hide class".

You are welcome to try copying it from its application's open source repository into your own.